# How to find() Data with object keys with Mongodb

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, object

If I have a Json Like

```
{
  "_id": "6307cec82ed2f6578c2c4f5a",
  "01 January 2023 Sunday": [
    {
      "date": "01 January 2023 Sunday",
      "location": "Kolkata, India",
      "Sunrise": [
        "06:17 AM"
      ],
      "Sunset": [
        "05:03 PM"
      ],
      "Moonrise": [
        "12:52 PM"
      ],
      "Moonset": [
        "02:08 AM, January 02"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find() values of the "01 January 2023 Sunday" key  in MongoDB

Comment: Are you trying to read the value of "01 January 2023 Sunday" or trying to query in MongoDB using the value?

Comment: Yes   value of '01 January 2023 Sunday"

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$exists`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "01 January 2023 Sunday": {
    $exists: true
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/upKPtvAdSXT)

I don't know your product and your schema could make sense for your needs, with that said I would consider reading about the [attribute pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern), you could benefit from restructuring your data.

Comment: i want the output like if 01 January 2023 Sunday then its returns the value of that keys